# FFMPEG - Is there any available func in ffmpeg lib which support getting audio file extension from codec/codec id?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Is there any available func in ffmpeg lib which support getting audio file extension from codec/codec id?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no.

If you want to save the elementary stream without a container, you can create your own extension table and map it to the codec_id-s which you will use.

On the other hand, if you use a (de)multiplexor via libavformat, some of them describe their supported extensions in a comma-separated string.

```
AVFormatContext *ctx;
//Acquire a format context...

char *exts = ctx->iformat->extensions; //demuxer's extensions (comma separated) 
exts = ctx->oformat->extensions; //returns the muxer's extensions
```

But anyway the documentation advises not to rely on the provided extensions. If I were you, I would create an extension map by myself.